# Attach a failover ip OVH

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

today i bought 4 ips from OVH for my dedicated server and i want to attach them . The documentation says to add a new `auto eth0:0` in to the network/interface but i want to make sure that this is accurate and dont mess anything up!

This is from ovh's docs:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address IP.DE.FAIL.OVER
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast IP.DE.FAIL.OVER
```

So, for 4 ips i will do `eth0:0` `eth0:1` `eth0:2` `eth0:3` and nothing else? Also my current ip has some stuff which i dont really know and dont match with the docs example.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 198.27.67.144
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 198.27.67.0
    broadcast 198.27.67.255
    gateway 198.27.67.254
```

- The adress is the public ip. I get that.
- The netmask OVH says to leave it as it is.
- I dont know what is the `network`
- what is the broadcast
- and what is the gateaway?

Also ca i use only the options from OVH's docs?
Thanks for your time :)

Oh and the OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7):

It's really as simple as adding the following to your /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address failoverIP
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast failoverIP
```

You don't add a gateway.  You also do not include a Network number - just the IP, netmask and broadcast (which should be the same as the IP).

Repeat, using eth0:2, eth0:3 and eth0:4 for your other 3 failover IP's.  You can also start at eth0:0, rather than eth0:1.

Source: My own OVH configuration

OVH Documentation: http://help.ovh.co.uk/IpFailover (use the same as Debian for Ubuntu)